# Time Machine detected that your backups can not be reliably restored

Tags: time-machine

I have a Synology with a 4TB hard drive and I'm getting this message. While I understand that I probably won't be able to continue using this for backup unless I erase it, I do wonder if I can access the files.
I can view the sparsebundle file and inside it files and folders as seen in the attached image.[image]
I have tried to double-click it so it will mount, but it didn't do anything.

Is there something I can do to access these files?